# Expected value of sum of two discrete random variables

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

[image]

**Correct Answer: 1.1**

My work: I'm not sure, but I tried to find the value for $c$ by summing joint pmf over all possible values of x and y, in order to use Law of Unconscious probabilist to calculate E[Y-X]. I am stuck on calculating $c$ however...

Answer (score 3):

The quantity that we want is $$\operatorname{E}[Y-X],$$ the expected value of the total number of tornadoes minus the number of tornadoes that result in at least 50 million in losses.  By linearity of expectation, we know that $$\operatorname{E}[Y-X] = \operatorname{E}[Y] - \operatorname{E}[X].$$  By definition, we have $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \sum_{y=0}^3 y \Pr[Y = y],$$ and similarly for $X$.  But since we are only given the joint mass function, i.e. $$p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \Pr[(X = x) \cap (Y = y)],$$ in order to compute the marginal probabilities, we need to write $$\Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{x=0}^3 \Pr[(X = x) \cap (Y = y)].$$  So for example, $$\Pr[Y = 2] = \Pr[(X = 0) \cap (Y = 2)] + \Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 2)] + \Pr[(X = 2) \cap (Y = 2)],$$ noting that $\Pr[(X = 3) \cap (Y = 2)] = 0$.

So, our entire problem-solving strategy may be better executed by using a table; e.g.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
& X = 0 & X = 1 & X = 2 & X = 3 & \text{Total} \\
\hline
Y = 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
Y = 1 & 2c & 3c & 0 & 0 & 5c \\
\hline
Y = 2 & 4c & 5c & 6c & 0 & 15c \\
\hline
Y = 3 & 6c & 7c & 8c & 9c & 30c  \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 12c & 15c & 14c & 9c & 50c
\end{array}$$
This tells us that, in order for the total probability to sum up to $1$, we must have $50c = 1$.  This also then gives us the marginal probabilities for $X$ and for $Y$, as shown in the row total and column total, from which we easily compute the required expected values.

Comment: I believe sum is 50c not 40c, but yes, this gives correct answer! thank you!

Comment: @MinYoungKim indeed, I had made an error—it is now fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to compute $c$ using that the probabilities of all your outcomes should sum to 1, i.e.
$$ \sum_{y=0}^3 \sum_{x=0}^y c(x + 2y) = 1,$$
which means that 
$$c = \left[\sum_{y=0}^3 \sum_{x=0}^y (x + 2y)\right]^{-1}$$
which in our case can be computed by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28sum+of+%28x%2B2+y%29+from+x%3D0+to+y%29+from+y+%3D+0+to+3) to be $\frac{1}{50}$.

Comment: The problem stipulates that $X \le Y$, not the other way around.  So your sum should read $$\sum_{y=0}^3 \sum_{x=0}^y x + 2y.$$

Comment: You are entirely correct. I've corrected my answer.